Compare all possible combinations of a multiple linear regression model in R based on p-values
I want to find the best combination of explanatory variables for a linear multiple regression model. I dont want a comparison based on Rsquared or other "overall" metrics. But I want to find a model which has only explanatory variables with p-values < 0.05.
I found this solution to create all possible models on stackoverflow (How to run all possible combinations in multiple linear regression model in R):
dat <- data.frame(
  Y = rnorm(100),
  X_1 = rnorm(100),
  X_2 = rnorm(100),
  X_3 = rnorm(100),
  X_4 = rnorm(100),
  X_5 = rnorm(100),
  X_6 = rnorm(100),
  X_7 = rnorm(100)
)

variables <- colnames(dat)[2:ncol(dat)]
formulas <- list()
for (i in seq_along(variables)) {
  tmp <- combn(variables, i)
  tmp <- apply(tmp, 2, paste, collapse="+")
  tmp <- paste0("Y~", tmp)
  formulas[[i]] <- tmp
}
formulas <- unlist(formulas)
formulas <- sapply(formulas, as.formula)

models <- lapply(formulas, lm, data=dat)

I added the following line to get the summary of all the possible models:
summaries <- lapply(models, summary, data=dat)
Now I want to find a way to compare all the summaries of the models based on their p-values and find the model that has only p-values < 0.05.
Get the p values of one model is easy:
summaries$Y~X_1+X_2$coefficients
But as I want to find the best model, I search for a way to compare all the models in summaries.
Additial information:
I found solutions with leaps::regsubsets (https://towardsdatascience.com/selecting-the-best-predictors-for-linear-regression-in-r-f385bf3d93e9) or with stats::step (Fitting a linear regression model in R)
but in both cases the results contain explanatory variables that are not significant (p-value >0.05)
